# Global configuration for http request headers

Tags: node-red

I'm setting up a node-red flow. This flow have serveral http requests. Each of this http request nodes need the same header parameter. For example i set msg.headers["Authorization"]. However i have to set this parameter for each http request node with a change node. Is there away to define this globaly and inject this automaticly to http request node?

Answer (score 0):

No

The closest you could do is to add a function or change node that adds the headers to a subflow then you can use instances of that subflow before each HTTP request node.

That way you only need to edit the subflow to change all the instances.